# Django annotate Avg on model field

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset, django-aggregation, django-annotate

I have these models:

```
class Agency(models.Model):
    pass


class User(models.Model):
    agency = models.ForeignKey(Agency)


class Feedback(models.Model):
    rating = models.DecimalField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

and I want to annotate a queryset with the average of all ratings. I expected this to work:

```
Feedback.objects.annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating')).values('rating', 'avg_rating')
```

but it just outputs this:

```
<QuerySet [{'rating': 0.8, 'avg_rating': 0.8}, {'rating': 0.2, 'avg_rating': 0.2}, {'rating': 0.6, 'avg_rating': 0.6}, {'rating': 1.0, 'avg_rating': 1.0}, {'rating': 0.4, 'avg_rating': 0.4}]>
```

As you can see the average should be 3.0. Where am I going wrong?

For a bit of clarity, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
agencies = Agency.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Coalesce(Subquery(
        Feedback.objects.filter(user__agency_id=OuterRef('pk'))
        .values('rating')
        .annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating', output_field=DecimalField()))
        .values('avg_rating')
    ), 0)
)
```

where the average rating is per agency. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to find out avg rating of a particular user ? Or the entire users who belong to one Agency ? Can you describe in words what is the use case ?

Answer (score 2):

```
Feedback.objects.aggregate(avg_rating=Avg('rating'))
```

Comment: I need it to be attached to each instance. So must be annotate

Comment: can you give the relationship between agency and Feedback ? Foreignkeys ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
agencies = Agency.objects.annotate(
avg_rating=Coalesce(Subquery(
    Feedback.objects.values('user__agency')
    .annotate(avg_rating=Avg('rating', output_field=DecimalField()))
    .values('avg_rating')
), 0)))
```